# Is a "creep" good, or bad, or both?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference, word-order

I have found these two definition of "creep" and would like to know is a "creep" considered good, or bad, or both?

> **creep** someone who tries to make someone more important like them by being very polite and helpful in a way that is not sincere.
>
> **creep** an unpleasant person, especially a man.

Comment: How could you read those definitions as good?

Comment: I need a deeper definition

Comment: Please can you also source the definitions? I agree with @cardinal that both of these sound negative, and correct

Comment: If you need a deeper definition, there are plenty of [dictionaries](https://onelook.com/?w=creep&ls=a) where you can start.

Answer (score 3):

A "creep" is someone (probably more likely to be male than female) who gives you a "creepy" feeling. I think a "creepy" feeling is when you feel like something unseen is *creeping*, or crawling, over the surface of your skin. Of course this is a folk etymology, so vote it down if you like, but I think it describes the meaning of the word very well.

A creep is more than "unpleasant". He is unpleasant in such an unsettling way as to cause fear, often fear of some kind of unspecified or unknown behavior on his part. "Creep" is *not* a good thing to call someone.

Your first definition is also of an unpleasant person, but it is not the definition of "creep". The word for that first definition is "kiss-ass" or "sycophant." He might *also* be a "creep", but that's not the usual definition.

Comment: AFAIK "creepiness" is the feeling of unease because we can't ascertain whether something is obviously a threat (as opposed to "horror" which is clear avoidance of something established to be dangerous).